# TextEdit Strange Error

Tags: macos, textedit

If I hit Spotlight type "TextEdit" and hit enter. TextEdit starts and after that I can open any txt file by double clicking on it. As you would expect. If I close TextEdit and click on any txt file it will flash very quick (as if it opens) and than nothing happens. No Console message and it does not open the file. I don't get it. I trashed the "com.apple.TextEdit.plist", but that did not change anything. Restart has no effect as well.

This seems spooky. Any ideas ?

Comment: Try adding TextEdit to the Dock - when it's open, right-click on the Dock icon, go to Options, and select "Keep in Dock". Then, quit TextEdit and try to open a text file by dragging the file onto the TextEdit icon.

Also, when you right-click on a text file, what does the "Open With" menu show?

Comment: I can open by dragging the Textfile on the DockIcon. I had it in the Dock anyway. Open with says TextEdit Default. But If I double click the problem persists.

Comment: Does it work in a new user account? Safe mode?

Comment: Yes it does work in Safe Boot Mode. So how can I solve this ?

Comment: And open -a TextEdit some.txt also opens the file quickly. ???

Answer (score 1):

So I found the solution. I tried to understand the underlying process better and therefore asked this question in a more general format here:

[Double Click to Open Program Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/137211/double-click-to-open-program-mac/137214?noredirect=1#comment163013_137214)

The answer is also the answer to this question =

Rebuilding Launch Service Database

Hope this is not too complicated :)